# Disable several buttons in Angular based on a global variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, button, readonly

I have a website and I want to be able to disable some validation buttons in case I have an `isReadOnly = true` (a global variable that I get from the backend), instead I go on all screens one by one and make `ngIf` everywhere. Is there an optiomal way to do that?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a directive to achieve that.

Here, a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kzv2ah).

Answer (score 0):

You could put your `isReadOnly` into a service and create a directive that set the `readonly` attribute of your button with your value.
It is similar to dince12 answer but it can works on all elements with readonly attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a read-only directive where you pass your isReadonly value as input or via shared service. Inside directive you can disabled any html control according to your need.